# How to use str.format() in re.compile() with multi line regex pattern

Tags: python, regex

I have a multi line regex, and I'd like to use string formatting to dynamically populate some parts of the regex. Example:

```
foo = 'Please feed {me} some pistachio ice cream!'
r = re.compile('Please feed \{{{}}\} '.format('me')
                'some {} ice cream!'.format('pistachio'))
r.findall(foo)
```

This raises a syntax error:

```
>>> foo = 'Please feed {me} some pistachio ice cream!'
>>> r = re.compile('Please feed \{{{}}\} '.format('me')
...                 'some {} ice cream!'.format('pistachio'))
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    'some {} ice cream!'.format('pistachio'))
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is a contrived example, but suppose I had a very long regex pattern broken into multiple lines for readability. How might I arbitrarily string format one or more lines?

Comment: You can add a `+` to concatenate the two strings or create just one string and use only a single `.format` call...

Comment: See http://ideone.com/d9q7lK.

Comment: This is not a regex problem. This is a misunderstanding on how to concatenate multiple `str.format()` results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a *Python syntax problem*, not a regex problem. The `re.compile()` function isn't being called, because you made a syntax error. You can't use implicit string concatenation (where two directly adjacent string literals are joined into one string object automatically) with `.format()` calls like that.

Either put the `.format()` at the end, or explicitly concatenate using `+`:

```
# one string, on two lines, implicitly concatenated then formatted
r = re.compile('Please feed {{{}}} '
               'some {} ice cream!'.format('me', 'pistachio'))

# two strings, concatenated explicitly after formatting
r = re.compile('Please feed {{{}}} '.format('me') +
               'some {} ice cream!'.format('pistachio'))
```

I also removed the `\` backslashes, otherwise you'd not have the properly doubled `{{` and `}}` characters in the template.

Demo, (without the `re.compile` call as that is not the issue here):

```
>>> ('Please feed {{{}}} '
...                'some {} ice cream!'.format('me', 'pistachio'))
'Please feed {me} some pistachio ice cream!'
>>> ('Please feed {{{}}} '.format('me') +
...                'some {} ice cream!'.format('pistachio'))
'Please feed {me} some pistachio ice cream!'
```